# How to add constraints for dynamic appending input fields in custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

how can I achieve the dynamic height of the cell while adding dynamic input fields in a custom table cell

```
- (IBAction)clickButtonAdd:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"test chekboc");
    CGFloat y ;
    CGFloat x ;
    UITextField *textField = nil;
       textField.frame = CGRectMake(x, y,100,30);
       textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,100,30)];
       textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
      [self.contentView addSubview:textField];
     NSLog(@"x value :: %f",x);
}
```

with the above code, I'm able to append the dynamic input fields. But the cell height is not increasing dynamically whenever we add a new input field.

**UPDATE**
[image: cell constraints]

[image]

These are the dynamically appended custom tableviewcells into the tableview, In the first appended cell contains a dynamically added text field.Whereas the second one represents the initial cell GUI. Question is to align the newly added input field and also to increase the cell height respectively

Comment: Are you trying to add a "vertical stack" of text fields? Or just adding a single text field? Or maybe a "grid" of fields?  You show *"x  = x + 120;"* but you're not doing anything with it...

Comment: I'm trying to create a Vertical stack.

Comment: OK - your best bet is to add a vertical `UIStackView` and add each new text field as an arranged subview. With constraints set up properly, that will automatically handle the cell height changes. If that's not clear, do a screen-cap of your current cell prototype, including showing the constraints, and add it to your question.

Comment: @DonMag updated the question

Answer (score 0):

A good approach for adding a "vertical stack" of views (such as text fields) is to use a `UIStackView`. Set up the constraints so the bottom of the stack view controls the bottom of the cell. As each new field is added to the stack view, it will automatically increase in height.

Here is an example layout (I tried to match your image):

[image]

Two important keys...

- Give the stack view a `Height` constraint so you can see it at design-time. But... edit that constraint and select `Placeholder / Remove at build time`. That way, when it has no arranged subviews, it will have a height of Zero, and it won't be prevented from expanding when views are added.
- Set the `Priority` on the bottom constraint to `999`. While not strictly necessary, it prevents constraint conflict warnings, as auto-layout makes multiple passes to determine the full layout.

A couple other notes on design:

- By setting the bottom constraint to `Priority: 999` you won't get IB warnings if you have the cell stretched a little taller than actually needed.
- To avoid labels stretching vertically, set their vertical `Content Hugging Priority: 1000`
- If you look closely at the constraints I setup, you'll see that some of the elements constraints are relative to each other, rather than to explicit constants. For example:

  - the "Set Date Range" label is vertically centered on "Date Picker", and the "Range Button" is vertically centered on the label.
  - the "Required" label is vertically centered on "Required Button", which is vertically spaced from "Range Button"
  - this will help keep elements aligned if you tweak any spacing

Here is the source for the .xib so you can more closely inspect the constraints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="15505" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina6_1" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="15510"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" rowHeight="166" id="PJb-fG-tbA">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="166"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
            <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="PJb-fG-tbA" id="kHE-Zl-zZn">
                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="166"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                <subviews>
                    <textField opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" verticalHuggingPriority="1000" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" borderStyle="roundedRect" placeholder="Question" textAlignment="natural" minimumFontSize="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="edU-F7-Rfh">
                        <rect key="frame" x="10" y="10" width="395" height="34"/>
                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                        <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits"/>
                    </textField>
                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="1000" text="Date Picker" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="UGi-vq-LEE">
                        <rect key="frame" x="10" y="57" width="180" height="21"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="180" id="H3h-PK-Tn5"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                    </label>
                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Set Date Range" textAlignment="right" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="J4r-by-M6A">
                        <rect key="frame" x="251" y="57" width="119" height="21"/>
                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                    </label>
                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="RBZ-hT-7ef" userLabel="RangeButton">
                        <rect key="frame" x="378" y="55" width="25" height="25"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.83741801979999997" green="0.83743780850000005" blue="0.83742713930000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="25" id="7aP-lC-w89"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="RBZ-hT-7ef" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="wgb-Ok-OF2"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </button>
                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Required" textAlignment="right" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="JQn-il-RKW">
                        <rect key="frame" x="301" y="93" width="69" height="21"/>
                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                    </label>
                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="qmA-hD-Bry" userLabel="RequiredButton">
                        <rect key="frame" x="378" y="91" width="25" height="25"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.83741801979999997" green="0.83743780850000005" blue="0.83742713930000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="25" id="YBm-hg-3dr"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="qmA-hD-Bry" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="u7w-4a-ue5"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </button>
                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" verticalHuggingPriority="1000" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="YJ4-1K-hxl" userLabel="TrashButton">
                        <rect key="frame" x="16" y="89" width="24" height="24"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.92003184559999995" green="0.73834878130000003" blue="0.71511208169999996" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="displayP3"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="YJ4-1K-hxl" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="djU-d0-anS"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="24" id="soO-f2-V8B"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </button>
                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" spacing="11" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Gg8-ZU-spe" userLabel="FieldHolderStackView">
                        <rect key="frame" x="10" y="124" width="100" height="30"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="30" placeholder="YES" id="iYY-1E-iFe"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="100" id="w6c-FN-Qk0"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </stackView>
                </subviews>
                <constraints>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="Gg8-ZU-spe" secondAttribute="bottom" priority="999" constant="10" id="0I5-0k-03U"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="qmA-hD-Bry" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="RBZ-hT-7ef" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="11" id="1P1-gw-Cwp"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="RBZ-hT-7ef" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="J4r-by-M6A" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="2Ao-ZT-eIv"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="YJ4-1K-hxl" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="UGi-vq-LEE" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="11" id="6hR-g2-Ihn"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="UGi-vq-LEE" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="kHE-Zl-zZn" secondAttribute="leading" constant="10" id="9CW-cL-yiq"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="RBZ-hT-7ef" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="J4r-by-M6A" secondAttribute="centerY" id="BBF-sa-WsF"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="Gg8-ZU-spe" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="YJ4-1K-hxl" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="11" id="FWT-S5-XZB"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="RBZ-hT-7ef" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="11" id="GIW-p6-CgM"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="edU-F7-Rfh" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="9" id="M5u-uX-qfk"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="UGi-vq-LEE" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="edU-F7-Rfh" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="13" id="Npo-gd-sot"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="edU-F7-Rfh" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="kHE-Zl-zZn" secondAttribute="top" constant="10" id="OT2-CJ-5fh"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="edU-F7-Rfh" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="kHE-Zl-zZn" secondAttribute="leading" constant="10" id="UUv-RU-c4W"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="qmA-hD-Bry" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="11" id="VdG-Gt-Q0N"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="JQn-il-RKW" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="qmA-hD-Bry" secondAttribute="centerY" id="Wu6-Sf-34N"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="qmA-hD-Bry" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="JQn-il-RKW" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="ZlM-6u-Tsh"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="Gg8-ZU-spe" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="kHE-Zl-zZn" secondAttribute="leading" constant="10" id="aQy-xo-rYY"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="J4r-by-M6A" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="UGi-vq-LEE" secondAttribute="centerY" id="eVE-sv-0Cf"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="YJ4-1K-hxl" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="kHE-Zl-zZn" secondAttribute="leading" constant="16" id="gdo-Xv-dBt"/>
                </constraints>
            </tableViewCellContentView>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="113.04347826086958" y="175.44642857142856"/>
        </tableViewCell>
    </objects>
</document>
```